# Передача всех элементов массива свойству

Tags: ооп, pascal, turbopascal

Можно ли передать свойству все элементы массива, чтобы затем указав индекс получить значение через свойство.

Описал ниже, что примерно хочу получить

```
    obj1 = object
    PRIVATE
           menu: array[1..3] of string;
    PUBLIC
          function GetMenu : string;
    END;

    function obj1.GetMenu : string;
    begin
         {GetMenu := menu[];}
    end;


    ......
    Var
       ob1: obj1;

    Begin
         writeln(ob1.GetMenu[2]);
    End.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
type
  TMenuArray = array[1..3] of string;

  obj1 = object
  private
    fMenu: TMenuArray;
  public
    function GetMenu: TMenuArray;
    property Menu: TMenuArray read fMenu;
  end;

function obj1.GetMenu: TMenuArray;
begin
  GetMenu := fMenu;
end;


  ......
  writeln(ob1.GetMenu[2]);
  writeln(ob1.Menu[2]);
```

Comment: invalid function result type

Comment: @SOFL - Турбопаскаля под рукой нет, в Delphi - компилируется.

Comment: Меня терзают смутные сомнения по поводу `property` в Turbo-Pascal'е...

Comment: @Alekcvp - поэтому и оставил код с `GetMenu`

Comment: Насчет property, оно естественно не заработает. Но вы двумя вариантами сделали.

Comment: Я именно про первый, при котором делаем свой тип массив и затем уже  с ним работаем. TMenuArray = array[1..3] of string; function GetMenu: TMenuArray; function obj1.GetMenu: TMenuArray;
begin
  GetMenu := fMenu;
end;

Comment: Именно при этом способе ссылается на  
invalid function result type

Comment: @SOFL на какой строчке?

Comment: @Igor  function GetMenu: TMenuArray;

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать через указатель на массив:

```
type  
  TMenuArray = array [1..3] of string; // можно сделать динамический массив
  PMenuArray = ^TMenuArray;

  TMyObject = object
  private
    fMenu: TMenuArray;
  public
    function Menu: PMenuArray;        
  end;

function TMyObject.Menu: PMenuArray;
begin
  Result := @fMenu;
end;

  .....
  writeln(ob1.Menu^[2]);
```

Comment: `array [1..3] of string;` - это не "динамический" массив. Почему это сработает, если не работает с `TMenuArray`?

Comment: Имеется в виду, что вместо указания диапазона можно использовать динамический массив. Сработает это [в теории] потому, что возвращается не сложный тип (массив), а обычный указатель. Кроме того, `Result := fMenu;` - это копирование всего массива при каждом обращении, `Result := @fMenu;` - это передача ссылки на массив. Минус же данного подхода в том, что по ссылке можно изменить сам массив. Чтобы этого избежать надо делать метод `function Menu(Index: Integer): string;` и использовать как `WriteLn(Menu(2));` но я не уверен что это вписывается в условия задачи.

Comment: Согласен. Убрал минус.